# Loop rolling mean python

Tags: python, loops, mean, rolling-computation

I am trying to calculate rolling mean for different window sizes.

I have the following working code:

```
df['h1'] = (np.log1p(df['r1']) - np.log1p(df['r2'])) * 100

df['h3'] = df['h1'][beg_date:end_date].rolling(window=3).mean()
df['h6'] = df['h1'][beg_date:end_date].rolling(window=6).mean()
df['h12'] = df['h1'][beg_date:end_date].rolling(window=12).mean()
```

I wanted to ask if there is a more elegant way of writing this code? In a loop perhaps.

Any tips would be helpful.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['h1'] = (np.log1p(df['r1']) - np.log1p(df['r2'])) * 100
windows = [3,6,12] # put whatever you want
for my_window in windows:
    window_name = 'h'+str(my_window)
    df[window_name] = df['h1'][beg_date:end_date].rolling(window=my_window).mean()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
for window in [3, 6, 12]:
    df[f"h{window}"] = df["h1"][beg_date:end_date].rolling(window=window).mean()
```

Comment: Hi guys. I've tried both codes and they both work perfectly. Thank you so much for helping out!